# What service account roles to deploy a scheduled Cloud Function?

Tags: firebase, gcp-iam

To deploy my Firebase project, I have setup a service account with the roles:

- Cloud Functions Admin
- Firebase Admin
- Service Account User

It works fine with Hosting and Cloud Functions triggered by Firestore or HTTPS, but it fails with a [function on schedule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

What additional role do I need?

Edit: the only related ouput messages are:

```
i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function schedule-statistics(europe-west3)...
...
✔  functions[schedule-statistics(europe-west3)]: Successful update operation. 
...
 Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
    schedule-statistics(europe-west3)
```

Edit: additional test: when deploying using my logged-in CLI on my machine, I see this additional message, which is missing when deploying with the service account:

```
✔  functions[schedule-statistics(europe-west3)]: Successful upsert schedule operation.
```

Edit: by adding logs as suggested by @Dharmaraj, I can see the missing permissions:

```
The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission \"cloudscheduler.jobs.get\"
...
The principal (user or service account) lacks IAM permission \"cloudscheduler.jobs.update\"
```

So when adding the "Cloud Scheduler Admin", it works!

I was misled because I already set this role to the service account but within **another project**, and it **does not propagate!** Lesson learned at the expense of a nice afternoon.

Comment: Doesn't the error message include which permission is missing ?

Comment: No it does not, I have added the related error messages.

Comment: Try deploying with `firebase deploy --only functions:schedule-statistics --debug`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: add role "Cloud Scheduler Admin".
The gotcha is: roles set to a service account in one project do not propagate to the same service account in other project.
The nice lesson is: add `--debug` to see additional logs, including missing permissions, thanks @Dharmaraj